# RegEx Error in Router

Tags: php, regex, routes, preg-match

**Update**

When I go to `/about/`, I get:

```
Route: contact
Get Param: about
```

When I go to `/contact/`, I get:

```
Route: about
Get Param: contact
```

---

Here's my code:

```
foreach ($routes as $route) {
            if (preg_match('/^' . $route . '$/', $uri)) {
                $controller = 'controllers/' . $route . '.php';

                if (file_exists($controller)) {
                    include_once($controller);
                } else {
                    echo '<h1>404 - Missing Controller</h1>';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<h1>404 - Missing Route</h1>';
            }
}
```

Problem is, I'm always seeing "Missing Route"... what's my problem here?

I get the same problem if I replace the `preg_match` with `if ($uri == $route)`

$routes = `Array ( [0] => about [1] => contact )`
$uri = `contact`

Directory structure:

controllers/
      About.php
      Contact.php
Router.php

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well your first problem is the lack of examples of what `$route` and `$uri` could be.  ;)

Comment: Please post some example `$route`s, expected behaviour, and resulting behaviour, as well as an example filesystem, and a value for `$uri`.  We need as much information as we can get.

Comment: Ah, sorry guys! Added. :)

Comment: What's the output for `getcwd()`, and what does your file system look like?

Comment: Added directory structure, sorry for the lack of detail.

Comment: i think your regex is not matching. Can you please paste the output for `print_r($routes);` as the first line in this code?

Comment: @abhi.gupta200297 `Array ( [0] => about [1] => contact )` - Already in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else condition is executing for every index except the matching one.

What i think you need to do is:

```
if(in_array($uri, $routes) {
            $controller = 'controllers/' . $uri . '.php';
            if (file_exists($controller)) {
                include_once($controller);
            } else {
                echo '<h1>404 - Missing Controller</h1>';
            }
 } 
 else {
            echo '<h1>404 - Missing Route</h1>';
      }
```

Also, if your controller names start with Capital letters, you need to add some logic to the making $controller variable to that it capitalizes the first character.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using preg_match at all?

```
if (preg_match('/^' . $route . '$/', $uri))
```

is the same as

```
if ($route == $uri)
```

unless for some reason you *want* your `$route` to have regular expression metacharacters in it.

Also, your output says you have a 404, but are you actually returning an HTTP response of 404?

Comment: I'm using `preg_match` because I plan on extending this to only allow certain characters. Also, 404 isn't the problem - I edited that code out for simplicity. I get the same result either way.

Comment: Tried your ($route == $uri) method, I still get the same problem. :S

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that it would solve your problem, only that you're doing unnecessary regex matching.